# How to create a function that will create multi level array based on another array

Tags: php, function, multidimensional-array

Basically I would like to create a function that will in turn create a multidimensional array based on another function. Here's the format of the array I need to create (end result):

```
'options' => array (
        'one' => array (
            'label' => 'Option One',
            'value' => 'one'
        ),
        'two' => array (
            'label' => 'Option Two',
            'value' => 'two'
        ),
        'three' => array (
            'label' => 'Option Three',
            'value' => 'three'
        )
    )
```

This will need to be created by a function using another array that was created to store wordpress categories:

```
$categories = get_categories('hide_empty=0&orderby=name');
$wp_cats = array();
foreach ($categories as $category_list ) {
       $wp_cats[$category_list->cat_ID] = $category_list->cat_name;
}
```

And here's the code I wrote to try accomplish what I've described but couldn't get it to work:

```
    function wcat2() {
    $i = 0;
    $categories = get_categories();
    foreach( $categories as $category ) {
        $i++;
        array (
        $i => array (
            $category->slug => $category->slug,
            $category->term_id  => $category->term_id
        ),
        );
    }
}
```

Any ideas of what I'm missing? Help would be much appreciated.

Update: Here's an illustration of what I need:
[image: descriptin 1]

[image: description 2]

Comment: for starters you are not saving the array to any variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like:

```
function wcat2() {
    $out = array();
    $categories = get_categories();
    foreach( $categories as $category ) {
        $out[$category->term_id] = array(
            'label' => $category->slug,
            'value' => $category->term_id
        );
    }
    return array('options'=>$out);
}
print_r(wcat2());
```

Create a blank variable $out, loop through the categories and on each loop append a new array in the desired format. I'm not sure which is which in regards to the slug/term_id, so you might need to switch those.

Comment: Hi Jonathan. Thanks for your help. It did work but the array didn't have all elements I need in it. I've added an image explaining which array I need and where which element should go.

Comment: I believe I did have an extra array in there. Check it now. That should match your requested output. However, like I said, under $category, I have no idea what fields there are, I was just guessing based on the code you had written. if slug/term_id are not in the right spot (or not the right property), you will need to fix them as I have no idea what slug/term_id refer to.

Comment: Also, you say the first key needs to be numbers 1,2,3 but in all the images it shows "one", "two", "three" as the key (text, not numbers).

Comment: That was it!!! I did edited out the `return array('options'=>$out);` and used `return $out;` instead which was what I needed (the 'options' is part of the other code that this function will go with). Thank you very much for your help! Much appreciated indeed!